# Eclipse custom renameParticipant, "Cannot determine URI", or "Problem encountered moving resources"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating a custom renameParticipant to rename the "APPNAME" variable within a project's make file. When I run the plugin the first time, I receive a pop-up with the error "Problem encountered moving resources", and when I re-run it, I get a different pop-up error "Cannot determine URI". With the second dialogue, the participant is automatically disabled until I reboot Eclipse.

```
public Change createChange(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException, OperationCanceledException
    {
        // Hash map and variable declarations.
        final HashMap<IFile, TextFileChange> changes = new HashMap<IFile, TextFileChange>();
        final String newProjName = getArguments().getNewName();
        // WorkspaceTracker is a class for workspace utilities.
        final IProject proj = WorkspaceTracker.getInstance().getCurrentProject();
        final String projName = proj.getName();
        // Find and open the Makefile. MAKEFILE_NAME is a final class variable.
        IResource res = proj.findMember(MAKEFILE_NAME);
        IFile makeIFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(res.getLocation());

        if (getArguments().getUpdateReferences())
        {
            // Verify hashmap is clear for the makefile changes
            TextFileChange change = changes.get(makeIFile);
            if (change == null && getTextChange(makeIFile) == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Read the makefile
                    final String fileIn = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(makeIFile.getLocationURI())),
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    // Use regex matcher to find match and add it to the change hashmap.
                    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(verbatim("^(APPNAME=)(.+)$"))
                        .matcher(fileIn);

                    // Error caused by the following code -----------------------------
                    // ("Problems encountered moving resources" OR "Could not locate URI")
                    while (matcher.find())
                    {
                        ReplaceEdit edit = new ReplaceEdit(matcher.start(), (matcher.end() - matcher.start()),
                            String.format("%1$s%2$s", matcher.group(1), newProjName));
                        if (change == null)
                        { // Add the changes
                            change = new TextFileChange(MAKEFILE_NAME, makeIFile);
                            change.setEdit(new MultiTextEdit());
                            changes.put(makeIFile, change);
                        }
                        change.addEdit(edit);
                        change.addTextEditGroup(new TextEditGroup(
                            String.format(verbatim("Updates Makefile APPNAME for %1$s"), newProjName), edit));
                    }
                    // End of error causing code----------------------------------------
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    CyConsole.getInstance().log(Level.ERROR,
                        String.format(verbatim("Failed to update Makefile references for %1$s. Error %2$s"), projName,
                            e));
                }
            }
        }
        CompositeChange result;
        if (changes.isEmpty())
        {
            result = null;
        }
        else
        {
            result = new CompositeChange("Rename project dependencies");
            for (Iterator<TextFileChange> iter = changes.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
            {
                result.add(iter.next());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The only other change that occurs during the rename process is the renaming of the project folder. I've considered that Eclipse renames the project folder first, then cannot find the path to the Makefile, but since an IFile is passed is this still the case?

Using the debugger, I've determined that the code does not fail until the changes are executed by 'fUndoChange= fChange.perform(new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 9));' from org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation [line: 258].

When a regex match for "APPNAME" isn't found, the resource/URI error dialogue does not appear (again, indicating that it is the execution of the Makefile change that is causing the errors).

Comment: After following it through the debugger (many, many, many times) I determined that it was caused by the order of changes. The other renameParticipant that was renaming the folder was causing my participant to lose track of the project (both as a system File, and as an IFile resource).

I've gone with the workaround of using 'createPreChange(...)', which implements my file specific changes before the directory-wide changes occur.

If anyone has a better solution that doesn't require 'createPreChange', I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You might want to look at existing code such as `org.eclipse.ant.ui` rename participants - it uses separate participants for project and file renames so that they know exactly what is changing.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, seeing a working version definitely helps me figure out where my code could be improved.